# sql azure: trigger error when inserting into temp table from inserted table

Tags: t-sql, trigger, azure-sql-database

I have a trigger on a sql azure table I am trying to set up.  Bear with me as this is one of my first triggers.
This trigger is supposed to track all changes to the table in an audit table.

- As I understand, you can only use temporary tables in SQL azure if you specifically create them. [Documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables)
- Also, as I understand, the **inserted** and **deleted** tables that are available within a trigger match the schema of the table the trigger is set up on.   [documented here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/BHCCAJCH.htm)

So I created a trigger on my table and in that trigger I create two temp tables, one for the inserted and dleted tables, with matching schemas.

When I try to insert into those temp tables from the inserted or deleted tables I get the following error:

> The data in row 3 was not commited
>   Error Source: Microsfoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools
>   Error Message: The row values(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they
>   alter multimple rows (4 rows).

This error occurs on these lines:

```
INSERT INTO #tempIns SELECT * FROM inserted
INSERT INTO #tempDel SELECT * FROM deleted
```

Here is my full tirgger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade] ON [dbo].[KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

DECLARE @bit INT ,
       @field INT ,
       @maxfield INT ,
       @char INT ,
       @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
       @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
       @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
       @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @Type CHAR(1) ,
       @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000),
       @RecordId VARCHAR(128),     
       @UserId VARCHAR(128)

--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited
SELECT @TableName = 'KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade'

-- date and user
SELECT         @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
               + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

---- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

---- get list of columns
CREATE TABLE #tempIns (
    [ShiftID] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [ShiftGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PortalID] [int] NULL,
    [DepartmentID] [int] NULL,
    [PlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NULL,
    [TradeDate] [date] NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL,
    [LastActionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AllowedRankID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [OwnerUserID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OwnerLocationID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerRankID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerPlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WorkerUserID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WorkerLocationID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerRankID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerPlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorRankID] [int] NULL,
    [SupervisorUserID] [int] NULL,
    [SupervisorEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorApproval] [bit] NULL,
    [Detail] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsPartialShift] [bit] NULL,
    [LastModifiedByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [confirmationGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Archived] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL);

CREATE TABLE #tempDel (
    [ShiftID] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [ShiftGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PortalID] [int] NULL,
    [DepartmentID] [int] NULL,
    [PlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NULL,
    [TradeDate] [date] NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL,
    [LastActionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AllowedRankID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [OwnerUserID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OwnerLocationID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerRankID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerPlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [OwnerEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WorkerUserID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WorkerLocationID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerRankID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerPlatoonID] [int] NULL,
    [WorkerEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorRankID] [int] NULL,
    [SupervisorUserID] [int] NULL,
    [SupervisorEmployeeID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SupervisorApproval] [bit] NULL,
    [Detail] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsPartialShift] [bit] NULL,
    [LastModifiedByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [confirmationGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Archived] [bit] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL);

INSERT INTO #tempIns SELECT * FROM inserted
INSERT INTO #tempDel SELECT * FROM deleted

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary Key value for record
SELECT @RecordId = '+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get User Id value for record
SELECT @UserId = '+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.LastModifiedByUserID,d.LastModifiedByUserID,0))' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END

SELECT @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
    SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
            AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field

    SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1

    SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)

    SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1

    IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 OR @Type IN ('I','D')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field

        SELECT @sql = '
            insert krisisShifts_Audit (  Type, 
                            TableName, 
                            PK, 
                            FieldName, 
                            OldValue, 
                            NewValue, 
                            UpdateDate, 
                            UserName,
                            RecordId,
                            UserId)
            select ''' + @Type 
                    + ''',''' + @TableName 
                    + ''',' + @PKSelect
                    + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
                    + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
                    + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
                    + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
                    + ',''' + @UserName 
                    + ''',' +  @RecordId
                    + ','   +  @UserId
                    + ' from #tempIns i full outer join #tempDel d'
                    + @PKCols
                    + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
                    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                                            + @fieldname
                                            + ' is not null)' 
                    + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                            + @fieldname
                                            + ' is null)' 
        EXEC (@sql)
    END

END
```

### QUESTION

Can someone help me figure out why I can not insert into my temp tables inside this trigger

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you are inserting records to the KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade table you can read from the inserted (logical table) but you should not use the deleted (logical table). My suggestion is create a separate trigger just for inserting records since you are beginning to work with triggers.

When you are deleting records from the the KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade table you then should use only the deleted (logical table). Try creating a trigger just for deleting.records.

Finally when you are updating records on the KrisisShifts_ShiftTrade table you should read from both logical tables, from the inserted and from the deleted tables. Again try creating a trigger just for updating records.

It seems you are using the following article to learn about triggers.

https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

SQLCoffee.com

Comment: yeah, that article is all over the web and has been quoted in stack overflow many times.  It is what I started with.  I have it working great on my local instance of SQL server but ran into this issue with Azure SQL.  In truth, after some reading over the last hour I think I will be moving towards temporal tables, they seem fantastic.

Comment: Please allow me to share the following article with you now that you are going to use temporal tables. http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0013.htm